# Prove the result is always a rational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

I am trying to prove the following:
If $a$ and $b$ are non-zero rational numbers, then $a^{b}$ is rational.
Any ideas or hints how to prove this?

Comment: $2^{1/2}$ is not rational.

Answer (score 7):

It is false. $2^{1/2}=\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2):

take $a=2$ and $b=\frac{3}{4}$ we get $2^{3/4}=\sqrt[4]{2^3}$ this is not rational